# What is the different between "start a bounty" vs "question eligible for bounty in 2 days"?

Tags: support, bounties

After asking a question, a link like this is shown beneath it:

> question eligible for bounty in 2 days

What is the difference between *start a bounty* and *question eligible for bounty in 2 days*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems rather self-explanatory to me.

*"start a bounty"* means you can start a bounty right now, since the timeout has already elapsed.

*"question eligible for bounty in 2 days"* means you need to wait 2 days before being able to start a bounty.

Related: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) → *When can I start a bounty?*